# Making moving circle with Composition in UWP

Tags: javascript, c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm new to using Composition class to access visual layer in UWP.
I'm trying change a easy program that a circle moving around in a specific area(canvas) from p5.js to UWP composition.
But I get stuck in making circle in composition and my define moving function.

below gif animation is what I want to make in UWP with composition class.

[image]

to help your understanding I copied source java-script source from nature of code written by daniel shiffman.

```
var m;
function setup()
{
    createCanvas(320, 160);
    frameRate(60);
    m =new  Mover(
                      createVector(random(width), random(height)), 
                      createVector(random(-5, 5), random(-5, 5))
                      );
}

function draw()
{
    background(255,100,100);

    m.display();
    m.update();
    m.chkEdge();
}

class Mover
{
    constructor(loc, vel)
    {
        this.loc = loc;
        this.vel = vel;
    }

    update() {
        this.acc = createVector(random(-1, 1), random(-1, 1));
        this.loc.add(this.vel);
        this.vel.add(this.acc);
        this.vel.limit(5);
    }
    display() {
        stroke(0);  
        fill(175);
        ellipse(this.loc.x, this.loc.y, 15, 15); 
    }
    chkEdge() {
         if ( this.loc.x > width) this.loc.x =0;
         else if ( this.loc.x<0) this.loc.x =width;
         if ( this.loc.y> height) this.loc.y = 0;
         else if (this.loc.y<0) this.loc.y=height;
    }
}
```

I want to write this program in UWP exactly same, but as I said before, I don't know how to make circle sprite visual and how to make my sprite visual move after finish function.

below is my C-sharp source.

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var ran = new Random();
        Vector3 velocity = new Vector3(30, 30, 0);
        Vector3 accel = new Vector3(ran.Next(-1, 1), ran.Next(-1, 1), 0);

        var cnv = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(mainCnv);
        var compositor = cnv.Compositor;
        var visual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        visual.Brush = compositor.CreateColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 100, 200));

        visual.Size = new Vector2(100f, 50.75f); // I want to make this circle

        visual.Offset = new Vector3(  // offset
            ran.Next(0, (int)mainCnv.Width),
            ran.Next(0, (int)mainCnv.Height),
            0); 

        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(mainCnv, visual);

        //while(true)
        {

            Vector3KeyFrameAnimation animation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();

            animation.InsertKeyFrame(
                1.0f,
                visual.Offset + velocity // ......... 
            );
            animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            //animation.IterationCount = 1;
            animation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;
            visual.StartAnimation("Offset", animation);

            //visual.Offset +=velocity; // this statement does not work.
            velocity += accel; //accel should be added velocity after behavior........
        }

    }
```

in mainPage.xaml I just defined "mainCnv" canvas.
below is gif animation that I create with UWP. I can't make it move and move and move. It just moves between same place repeatedly.
[image]

is It possible to make same program in UWP?
If I can't, I'm fine just using Xaml.UI Layer. I'm just curious that I can do same thing in composition.
Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, you could use Win2D to approach. And there is related [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/blob/master/ExampleGallery/LayersExample.xaml#L8) you refer.

```
public void Update(Size controlSize)
{
    // Move the ball.
    Position += Velocity;

    // Bounce if we hit the edge.
    Vector2 topLeft = new Vector2(Radius);
    Vector2 bottomRight = controlSize.ToVector2() - new Vector2(Radius);

    float bounceX = (Position.X < topLeft.X || Position.X > bottomRight.X) ? -1 : 1;
    float bounceY = (Position.Y < topLeft.Y || Position.Y > bottomRight.Y) ? -1 : 1;

    Velocity *= new Vector2(bounceX, bounceY);

    Position = Vector2.Clamp(Position, topLeft, bottomRight);

    // Gradually fade in and out.
    FadeAge += FadeSpeed;
}
```